# C# auto-insert data from SQL table to web application

Tags: c#, html, sql, azure, pgadmin

I have a problem with inserting values from a SQL table (pgadmin) to a web application. If I check my table in pgadmin, all is ok:

[image]

But if I push it into application on Azure, it returns only:

[image]

I don't know where the problem is.

display.data.razor:

```
@page "/displaydata"
@using WebApplication1.Data;
@using WebApplication1.Services;
@inherits OwningComponentBase<DataService>

<h1>Display data</h1>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            id
        </th>
        <th>
            Nazov IMG
        </th>
        <th>
            label
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (WebApplication1.Data.Dataset item in sc)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.relid</td>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>@item.label</td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

@code {
    public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Dataset> sc;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        sc = Service.displaydata();
        foreach (var item in sc)
        {
            Console.Write(@item.relid + " " + @item.label);
        }
}
}
```

Result of Console.Write(@item.relid + " " + @item.label):

```
2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)2 "Gold(99.64134)
```

DataService:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Data;
namespace WebApplication1.Services
{
    public class DataService
    {
        protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbcontext;
        public DataService(ApplicationDbContext _db)
        {
            _dbcontext = _db;
        }
        public List<Dataset> displaydata()
        {
            return _dbcontext.results.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Dataset> results { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the data source of sc when debugging? Or let us look at the query statement of your method at runtime.

Comment: I edited it, maybe now ? @JasonPan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please follow my suggestions to troubleshoot**

1. *First make sure that when running locally, the data is displayed in the foreach is correct.*
2. *Log in to the scm website, or click on the App service editor in the portal, and check the web.config file. Or check the Connection strings in the Configuration.*

   [image]

   **The difference:**

   If it is set in Connection strings, the database connection string in web.config will be overwritten. If not, then the web program will connect according to the string in web.config.

   [image]
3. *According to the string, use the SSMS tool to find the database and check whether the data is consistent with the error data displayed on the page.*
4. If the data displayed locally is incorrect in the first step, it is recommended that you create a new demo code and upload it to github so that we can perform local debugging. (Be careful to hide your confidential information)